# How to find all xml nodes with same attribute value

Tags: jquery, xml, search, attributes

I have to query for the content of a XML tag and match all parent nodes with the same ID and show the result on the page.

pseudo code:

1. load XML file
2. get input from user (var inputTerm)
3. find inputTerm in XML tag `<term>`
4. get the ID of the parent node `<entry>`
5. find all entry nodes with the same ID from inputTerm
6. show all child nodes for these entries

I got to step 4 in the pseudo code but do not know how to go on. I have to loop again through the XML file, to find all entry tags with the identic ID.

XML:

```
<terms>
    <entry ID="1">
        <language>en</language>
        <term>user</term>
        <state>text</state>
        <use>text</use>
        <definition>text</definition>
        <definition-source>text</definition-source>
        <source>text</source>
        <circle>text</circle>
    </entry>
    <entry ID="1">
        <language>de</language>
        <term>user1</term>
        <state>text</state>
        <use>text</use>
        <definition>text</definition>
        <definition-source>text</definition-source>
        <source>text</source>
        <circle>text</circle>
    </entry>
    <entry ID="2">[...]</entry>
    [...]
</term>
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET" ,
  url: "assets/db/export.xml" ,
  dataType: "xml" ,
  success: function(xml) {

    $('entry', xml).each(function() {
      var $entry = $(this)
      var xterm = $entry.find("term").text();

      $('#submit').click(function() {
        // get input from user
        var inputTerm = $('#find-term').val();
        // match user input and XML content
        if (inputTerm === xterm) {
          // get ID from matching term
          var matchingID = $entry.attr('ID');
          console.log(matchingID);
          // How to go on here?
          var language = $entry.find("language").text();
          var term = $entry.find("term").text();
          var state = $entry.find("state").text();
          var use = $entry.find("use").text();
          var definition = $entry.find("definition").text();
          var definitionSource = $entry.find("definition-source").text();
          var source = $entry.find("source").text();
          var circle = $entry.find("circle").text();
          // show results
          $('.values').append('<li>' + language + '</li>');
          $('.term').append('<li>' + term + '</li>');
          $('.state').append('<li>' + state + '</li>');
          $('.usage').append('<li>' + use + '</li>');
          $('.definition').append('<li>' + definition + '</li>');
          $('.definition-source').append('<li>' + definitionSource + '</li>');
          $('.source').append('<li>' + source + '</li>');
          $('.circle').append('<li>' + circle + '</li>');
        }
        else {
          console.log("No entry found.");
        }
      });
    })
  }     
});
```

Can I add a second each and how to match all entries with the same ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

1. load XML file
2. when that's done, enable the submit button (keep it disabled initially)
3. on click,

   1. search the XML doc for matching terms
   2. extract value(s) of the ID attribute(s) associated to the match(es)
   3. filter XML entries according to those IDs
   4. add found results to page

I am assuming you want to support case-insensitive term search, so I've included a helper for that:

```js
// helper for jQuery.fn.filter
function containsCaseInsensitive(searchTerm) {
    return function () {
        return $(this).text().toUpperCase().includes(searchTerm.toUpperCase());
    };
}

$.get("assets/db/export.xml").done(function (exportXml) {
    var $exportXml = $(exportXml);

    // enable button and attach event handler after download is done
    $('#submit').prop("disabled", false).click(function() {
        var searchTerm = $('#find-term').val();
        var $terms = $exportXml.find("term").filter(containsCaseInsensitive(searchTerm));
        var ids = $terms.map(function () { return $(this).parent().attr("ID"); }).toArray();
        var $entries = $exportXml.find("entry").filter(function () { return ids.includes( $(this).attr("ID") ); });

        // don't forget to empty out the search result display

        if (!$entries.length) alert("No entry found.");

        $entries.each(function () {
            var $entry = $(this);
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("language").text()}).appendTo(".values");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("term").text()}).appendTo(".term");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("state").text()}).appendTo(".state");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("use").text()}).appendTo(".usage");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("definition").text()}).appendTo(".definition");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("definition-source").text()}).appendTo(".definition-source");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("source").text()}).appendTo(".source");
            $("<li>", {text: $entry.children("circle").text()}).appendTo(".circle");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and the neat code. A case-insensitive search is not necessary, because it is a search for terminology, so only exact matches matter. I changed your filter function to filter just exact matches.

Comment: That was the intent - adapt as needed. :)